# Adding hex values in a loop

Tags: perl, hex

I have to generate a text file which contains a lot of hexadecimal values. The hex values are in arithmetic progression, with a difference of 0x1000000.

The output in the file should be as:

```
sum(0x08000000, "text")
sum(0x09000000, "some other text")
sum(0x0A000000, "yet another text")
...
sum(0x10000000, "random something")
...
```

Is there any way I can run a loop to generate these values?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried?

Comment: for(my $i = 0x8000000; $i <= 0x10000000; $i += 0x1000000)
    print "sum ", hex $i, "\n"; I Tried this with and without the hex keyword. It prints all values in decimal notation.

Comment: Also tried inside the loop : print sprintf "%X", $i, "\n"; This gives the required values but throws a warning "Redundant argument in sprintf at ..."

Comment: That's because you've got your `sprintf` wrong. It should be `print sprintf ("%X\n", $i )`. Or just `printf ( "%X\n", $i );` because printing a sprintf is redundant

Comment: oh yes, i got it now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need `printf` or `sprintf` for outputting hex.

Perl "understands" hex just fine, if you stick `0x` in front of it, it's hex.

For output formatting though, it'll default to 'normal' numeric representation - so instead you want either `printf` or `sprintf` (they do the same thing, but the latter 'prints' to a string).

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print 0x10,"\n";

my $value = 0x20;
$value += 0x1F;

print $value,"\n";

printf ("%X\n", $value);
```

The format string is either `%X` for upper case hex, or `%x` to use lowercase.

So for your example:

```
for ( my $i = 0x8000000; $i <= 0x10000000; $i += 0x1000000 ) {
   printf( "sum 0x%x\n", $i );
}
```